# Does function declaration order matter in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm learning Redux with [Dan Abramov's Redux course videos on http://egghead.io](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux).

I had this code, working fine:

```
export const todoApp = (state = {}, action) => {
    return {
        todos: todos(state.todos, action),
        visibilityFilter: visibilityFilter(state.visibilityFilter, action),
    }
}

export const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    // ...implementation
};

const visibilityFilter = (state = "SHOW_ALL", action) => {
    // ...implementation
}
```

Then I tried to replace the `todoApp` reducer function with one generated with the `combineReducers` helper function:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

export const todoApp = combineReducers({
    todos: todos,
    visibilityFilter: visibilityFilter,
});

export const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    // ...implementation
};

const visibilityFilter = (state = "SHOW_ALL", action) => {
    // ...implementation
}
```

But when I try to run the unit tests (which were working fine) I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: todos is not defined
```

However, if I cut and copy the `todoApp` function definition to the bottom of the file (like in the code below), everything works fine again!

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

export const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    // ...implementation
};

const visibilityFilter = (state = "SHOW_ALL", action) => {
    // ...implementation
}

export const todoApp = combineReducers({
    todos: todos,
    visibilityFilter: visibilityFilter,
});
```

I have also tried to place the `todoApp` definition between the `todos` and `visibilityFilter` functions. In that case, I get the error

```
ReferenceError: visibilityFilter is not defined
```

So if I create the `todoApp` reducer function myself at the top of the file everything works fine, regardless of the function declaration order, but if I use the `combineReducers` helper function, I need to do it under all the other declarations.

Can somebody explain me why is this happening and what are the good practices to be followed concerning the declaration order?

Comment: when declaring the function as a variable order does matter. if they were function statements instead of expressions, order doesn't matter, since those get hoisted.

Comment: @dandavis I realize that. My guess is that `combineReducers` is an actual invocation while `todoApp` is just a function. Since the invocation actually looks for the values of `visibilityFilter` and `todos`, it reports the error whereas the `todoApp` declaration does not call for immediate lookup.

Comment: replacing `export const` with `var` makes the issue much more obvious to traditional JSers like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with ECMAScript's way of evaluation and initialization. In your first snippet, where `todoApp` shows up before the other functions:

```
export const todoApp = (state = {}, action) => {
  return {
    todos: todos(state.todos, action),
    visibilityFilter: visibilityFilter(state.visibilityFilter, action),
  }
}
```

The reason why this does not throw a ReferenceError is because the return value is evaluated *after* `todos` and `visibilityFilter` is defined. This is described in the [ECMAScript 2018 Specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation):

> #### 9.2.12 FunctionDeclarationInstantiation ( *func*, *argumentsList* )
>
> > **NOTE 1** [...] All other bindings are initialized during evaluation of the function body.

Here, the specification notes that when FunctionDeclarationInstantiation is called (which is called when you create a new function such as `todoApp`, the bindings (such as variables or return values) are evaluated *during* the evaluation of the function body. This implies that the function body is *not* evaluated when the function is created thus the return value object is not known to contain a reference to `todos` or `visibilityFilter` which does not exist yet. This is is also reinforced in [Object Initializers](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-initializer):

> #### 12.2.6 Object Initializer
>
> > **NOTE 1** An object initializer is an expression describing the initialization of an Object, written in a form resembling a literal. It is a list of zero or more pairs of property keys and associated values, enclosed in curly brackets. The values need not be literals; they are evaluated each time the object initializer is evaluated.

The last line mentions that the values of an object are not evaluated until the object itself is evaluated.

*Thus, since the return value of `todoApp` is not evaluated until you actually call `todoApp`, and object values are not evaluated until the return value is evaluated, no ReferenceError is reported because the `todos` and `visibilityFilter` references are not evaluated*.

---

On the contrary, your second example is evaluated before `todos` and `visibilityFilter` are defined:

```
export const todoApp = combineReducers({
  todos: todos,
  visibilityFilter: visibilityFilter,
});
```

Here, `combineReducers` is a function call. Because `todos` and `visibilityFilter` are function *expressions*, they are not hoisted, thus the `combineReducers` call is evaluated before they exist. The object initializer is evaluated because it's an argument to `combineReducers`, and once the initializer is evaluated, the values are evaluated. The reference to `todos` and `visibilityFilter` give a ReferenceError because they do not exist yet.

This also explains the third example as it works because `combineReducers` is called *after* `todos` and `visibilityFilter` are defined. Your final attempt at putting `todosApp` between `todos` and `visibilityFilter` raises another ReferenceError because `todos` will be evaluated and exist but `visibilityFilter` will not because it is not hoisted.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.  If you use the `function` keyword, the declaration is "hoisted" to the top of the scope, in the same way that the `var` keyword works.

If you use `const` or `let`, then the variable doesn't actually "exist" until the line that it's declared on, and is `undefined` above that.  (The technical term for this is the "Temporal Dead Zone".)

Comment: no, both expressions and statements use the word `function`, and var and functions hoist differently in that `var`s are `undefined` but function statements are defined. good mention of TDZ though.

Comment: In addition a function _declaration_ is hoisted in full - not at all similar to how variables are hoisted.